# Pyinstaller generate EXE file outside dist folder

Tags: python, pyinstaller, executable, auto-py-to-exe

I'am using Pyinstaller package to build a python desktop app, however Pyinstaller seems to put the bundled exe file outside _internal folder
is there a solution I can try ?
Thanks in advance

[output by Pyinstaller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3eUo.png)
[_internal folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMx3z.png)

my goal is to package all the app in a folder (dist)
that exe file must be inside _internal folder

Comment: What's the problem?  It's creating an exe, right?  That's what you want.  The exe should have all of those `_internal` files embedded inside.

Comment: yeah the exe is generated succesfully and working ,but App structure that is created by Pyinstaller is like this  ( Voice Record/_internal  +  Voice Record/VoiceRecord.exe) ,I want Pyinstaller to generate (Voice Record.exe) inside (_internel) folder

Comment: Why??  What possible difference does it make?

Comment: @Tim Roberts  if make forms by wxFormBuilder,it use relative path.It is the reason ,why I want they in onedir,but not like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the update logs,on Pyinstaller's document:https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/CHANGES.html#id2

it says:

> Restructure onedir mode builds so that everything except the executable (and if you’re using external PYZ archive mode) are hidden inside a sub-directory. This sub-directory’s name defaults to but may be configured with a new --contents-directory option. Onefile applications and macOS bundles are unaffected. (#7713.pkg_internal.app)

It means: from the verison ,6.0.0, it will build with a dir named _interne,when  you choose to build by onedir.

So,a simple way to go back,is , make the version no bigger than 6.0.0.such as 5.13.2. It works well for me.

Also ,from the github issue.Below:

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/7713

Pyinstall may give us a way to build exe file (use onedir),no create a dir named _interne.But,I can not find it.

Sorry for that,English is not my mother tongue.I have tried my best to get the grammar correct.

Comment: Thanks a lot , that worked perfectly for me !

Answer (score 4):

sorry I'm not professional in English but I'm trying my best
I had the same problem but I search the internet and I come to this conclusion
that if you add `--contents-directory "."` to your cmd code the exe file and datas will be in one folder

but it's necessary to pass --onedir too

will be in one folder like this:

> python -m PyInstaller --onedir --contents-directory "." file.py